# Exporting data from Oracle query to excel using query

Tags: oracle, excel, export-to-excel

I am having a select query, the result of which i want to be exported in a excel file using Oracle query and not any in-built operations.

I am using `TOAD for Oracle`. I am not sure if this is possible or not.

Any help would be of great use.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Why have you tagged this 'mysql' ?

Answer (score 1):

In Toad, it's pretty straightforward:

- Run your query
- click the "Export dataset" button
- change export format to "Excel File"
- enter a filename

Comment: To be precise, I want to add that the select query is a part of procedure that is executed periodically once a day. So in between other query there is this one query, the result of which i want to save in a excel file.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of pushing it into Excel, why not "pull" it into Excel? See get external data. An added bonus is that you can add this to your windows task scheduler that will update it for you.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/connect-to-import-external-data-HP010089898.aspx